# How do I make group-by ignore white-space in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have an xml file which I need to group-by using xsl:for-each-group. Everything works fine but the problem comes from when there is elements which have white space at the end of them (e.g. `<word>test </word> and <word>test</word>`) but I need these to be considered as one group.

Here's the sample xml file:

```
<u>
  <s>
    <w>this </w>
    <w>is </w>
    <w>a </w>
    <w>test </w>
  </s>
  <s>
    <w>this</w>
    <w>is</w>
    <w>a</w>
    <w>test</w>
  </s>
<u>
```

Here's the xslt code

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="bncDoc/stext/div/u/s" group-by="w" >
  <tr>  
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted an example of the output that you are trying to produce. It is not clear whether you need to adjust your select statement or the group-by (or both).

Comment: I just need to adjust the group-by statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="bncDoc/stext/div/u/s/w" group-by="normalize-space()">
   <!-- ... -->
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I did it using normalize-space but I get this error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of normalize-space()

Comment: @Peymankh: If there are multiple `<word>` children, which one do you want to group on?

Comment: I want to group them based on the <word>

Comment: @Peymankh: Yes, but apparently there is *more than one word* per group, isn't there?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit the question with a sample XML file, see if you can get any clue out of it.

Comment: @Peymankh: See modified answer. Tip for future: always include the relevant XML with your question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the answer:

You just need to use the normailize-space() in this way:

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="bncDoc/stext/div/u/s/w" group-by="normalize-space((text())">
        .
        .
        .
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: With that `@select`, you could also just use `group-by="normalize-space()"`.  What you wanted was each unique `<w>`. It would have been helpful to mention that in the question, and Tomalak could have given you an exact answer.

Comment: By the way, +1 for answering your own question.

Comment: @Mads: That's the exactly answer I've given a few hours ago…

Comment: @Tomalak - so it is.  I had seen the first version and didn't notice the edit.

Comment: I'm gonna leave my answer over here but will set @Tomalak's answer as the correct answer since he came up with it.